# wp_insert_post and custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy

Hi I need some help with custom taxonomy and wp_insert_post.

I have a Custom Post Type "Locations" and the custom taxonomy called "poicategory".

My problem is when I insert the post with wp_insert_post the post taxonomy is not created correctly. If I´m watching in Backend post is created but no category is connected to post. When I go in post edit and watch the categories are set to the post (see images).

First image: the created post in Backend -> No categories set ->
 edit the created post and you see in POI Kategorien 3 selected Categories

Second image: POI Category overview in Backend -> No post in Category.

My first try was this code snipped:

```
    $ids = array (42,43,44);
    $defaults = array(
    'post_type' => 'locations',
    'post_title' => $postTitle,
    'post_status' => 'draft',
    'comment_status' => 'closed',
    'tax_input' => array(
        'poicategory' => $ids
    ),
    'post_author' => 1,
    'meta_input' => $post_meta,
);
$mh_post_id = wp_insert_post($defaults, true);
if ($mh_post_id != 0 && $mh_post_id != false) {
    set_post_thumbnail($mh_post_id, $_SESSION['mediaDataID'][0]);
    add_post_meta($mh_post_id, '_yoast_wpseo_primary_poicategory', $parentCat);
    destroySession();
}
```

with this explaned result. So I searched a bit around and found something. So I switch my code to this :

```
    $ids = array (42,43,44);
    $defaults = array(
    'post_type' => 'locations',
    'post_title' => $postTitle,
    'post_status' => 'draft',
    'comment_status' => 'closed',
    'post_author' => 1,
    'meta_input' => $post_meta,
);


$mh_post_id = wp_insert_post($defaults, true);
if ($mh_post_id != 0 && $mh_post_id != false) {
    set_post_thumbnail($mh_post_id, $_SESSION['mediaDataID'][0]);
    add_post_meta($mh_post_id, '_yoast_wpseo_primary_poicategory', $parentCat);
    wp_set_object_terms($mh_post_id, $ids, 'poicategory', false);
    destroySession();
}
```

But the result is the same. And now I have no idear whats wrong.
I hope someone can help me :).

[image: Post Backend]

[image: POICategory Backend]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the answer. The code is correct.
Wordpress do in taxonomy.php Line 3392

```
    $count += (int) $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->term_relationships, $wpdb->posts WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id AND post_status = 'publish' AND post_type IN ('" . implode("', '", $object_types ) . "') AND term_taxonomy_id = %d", $term ) );
```

$count is empty because post_status = 'publish' in WHERE statement and my post are saved as draft.

I think so that´s the reason why the counter are empty on second image.